# SQL Server 2005 - Check/Validate null values and add to results

Tags: sql-server

Please see below table structure and output required (struggling to right this)

```
Table: Employees
Structure
EmpID   Manager   Account Manager
1       Conrad    Craig
2       Rob        
3       Holly     Luke

Output Required (If manager is not null and account manager is not null then Count is 1+1)

EmpdId   Count
1         2
2         1
3         2
```

I'm struggling to write query which can give me above output

So we are checking of null for manager and account manager. And if they are not null then assign value 1 to them and add them up.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you could do like this:

```
SELECT EmpId 
CASE WHEN Manager IS NOT NULL AND Account Manager IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS Count
FROM TBL
```

Comment: And you can extend your statement with more WHEN-Queries like CASE WHEN x = y THEN 1 WHEN y <> x THEN 2 WHEN y IS NULL AND x IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 3 END

Comment: I have got multiple fields (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3) and if all are not null then result should be 1+1+1.....which is 3. Above is fine with two fields, but I have lot of fields for which I need to check if they are null or not and add up all values...

Comment: I have got multiple fields (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3) and if all are not null then result should be 1+1+1.....which is 3. Above is fine with two fields, but I have lot of fields for which I need to check if they are null or not and add up all values...

Comment: Another idea is
`SELECT EmpId, CASE WHEN Manager IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Account Manager IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ...`

At the end you can put the count logic in a function and just paste the field-value